# Find a jquery element whose parent contains some text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have the following structure :

```
<td width="270px">
<img class="bullet" border="0" valign="top" src="gray-bullet.gif">
this is the text
</td>
```

I need a query to select the img with class bullet whose parent contains the text "this is the text"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier if you gave that text an element of its own. Then you can give it attributes, and jQuery them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` selector.

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

Try this:

```
  $('td:contains("this is the text") img.bullet');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Q26/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with filter:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(':contains(this is the text)');
}).find('img.bullet');
```

---

You need to use `.filter()` function with `:contains()` method which looks for contained text.

---

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Z32/) try clicking on image.